# probability distribution find the constant c

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

answer=0.3+cx+c(x-2)=1, →2c(x-1)=0.7

using the integral(0→4)

( X^2/2 - x )(0→4)= f(4)-f(0) =4

2c*4=0.7

therefore c= 0.0875

correct? i'm not sure.

Comment: Are you sure, that the distribution is continuous ? It seems to me, that the distribution is discrete. For a continuous distribution $P(X=a)$ is zero.

Comment: oh,,because it;s not include X=1? that's why its discrete?

Comment: No, the reason is, that the probability that a continuous random  variable has a value of exact $a$ is zero. In your case $a=0$ and $P(X=0)=0.3$ This is clearly not zero.

Comment: ok,however, my answer is still correct?

Comment: I think this needs clarification.  I agree with prior comments that this looks discrete, not continuous.  But what does $p(x=4)=c(x-2)$ mean?  Does it mean $p(x=4)=2c$ since $x=4$?  If so, then I suppose we'd add up the 4 cases to get $1 = .3 + 2c+3c+2c$ and solve for $c$.  Not certain this is what is intended, however.

Comment: oh i think ,i missed some information... that mean's C =0.1 right?

Comment: Yeah, that´s right.